# Forward DHCP assignment to my ISP rather than have router's DHCP server assign IPs

Tags: dhcp

Okay, I don't know if this is possible, but I was wondering if it were possible to turn of the DHCP server in my router and have my ISP assign global IP addresses to all the devices on my network.

Comment: This probably belongs on Super User.

Comment: I was thinking that too, but I figured I'd find a lot of networking know-how on here.

Comment: No. The ISP isn't going to assign ip addresses to your internal hosts/devices. Ignoring the technical aspects of your question, this isn't something ISP's do.

Comment: If your ISP offers this service (multiple IP addresses for a single connection), then it should work. Turn off your router's DHCP server and set the router to bridging mode. If it's a pure Ethernet router, connect the modem to a LAN port rather than the WAN/Internet port. Note that most ISPs just don't do things this way.

Comment: @joeqwerty, well if his router supported IPv6, and he wanted to get IPv6 addresses, then it would be possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your router nobody can say for certain; if your router does support it, it'll probably be described as "bridged mode" or similar.  Check with your ISP first to make sure they will give you that many addresses and don't have other restrictions (some still don't permit anything but their provided router or some designated machine, and may check MAC addresses in an attempt to enforce this).

Comment: I have a DD-WRT enabled router. And I am not dealing with a modem or anything.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a good idea. That said -

This depends on your ISP. If they will assign you multiple addresses via DHCP, the easiest way to do this would be to get rid of the router entirely and use a switch: plug one port on the switch into the LAN port on your DSL/cable modem, then your other devices also plug into the switch.

Most ISP's don't do this, and all of your devices will be exposed to the internet without the benefit of NAT or firewall functionality from the router.